# How to show different activities for different ListView items?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with several items and every item has it own `Activity` class to show details. How can I switch to an appropriate activity when user selects and item in this `ListView`?

My current code is following:

```
 ListView listView;
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

 String[] hotel = {"one room", "double room", "suit", "vip"};

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);  
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hotel);

   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Use [switch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement

Comment: Move text from title to the main body and introduce new title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add setOnItemClickListener to your listView in onCreate under `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` :

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                if(position == 0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OneRoomActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               else if(position == 1){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DoubleRoomActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               //Do as above for rest of the list items
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.